# Allowing an user to remove an item from a List

Tags: c#, list, generics

I'm self-teaching myself C# and have been stuck trying to figure out on how to allow a user to be able to remove an item along with its index number from a list ***by either entering their index number or typing the word in.***

I've already googled and tried out many ways to do it, but each time I figured out a way, it would delete the element I would choose, but the index didn't go away. Example( List : 0.hat, 1.mat, 2.fat and whenever I would enter "1" or "mat" to remove 'mat' it would then display the list as 0.hat 1.fat and I want it to display 0.hat, 2.fat)

This is what I recently tried doing:

```
  string[] stringList = new string[] { "hat", "mat", "fat" };
        //Creating list
        List<string> list = new List<string>(stringList);
        string answer;
        //ordering list backwards Z-A
        list.Sort((a, b) => -1 * a.CompareTo(b));
        //loop to allow them to continue removing items
        while (true)
        {
            //Displaying list to console
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                //display list
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", i, list[i]);
            }

            //This is blank
            Console.WriteLine();
            //instructions what to do
            Console.WriteLine("Choose from the list to remove an item: ");
            //this will store the users input
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            answer = answer.ToLower();

            -- this is where I put the removing at --

            //Making sure user does not crash program
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
            {
                var index = list.FindIndex(i => i == answer);
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        list.RemoveAt(index);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The method I used here doesn't remove anything. 
I'm having a hard time understanding.
If someone could provide some insight that would be great. Thanks

Comment: btw, comments in C# are not enclosed in double-dashes like you have here. they start with // or are enclosed like: /* some comment here */

Comment: Yeah I know that, that part isn't in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the string without having to look for the index by passing the string into `.Remove()` method. Also remove the `foreach` loop as it is redundant, you are not doing anything there.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
{
    list.Remove(answer);
}
```

Using `Dictionary` you can access key or value and remove as you need.

```
var list = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 0, "hat" },
    { 1, "mat" },
    { 2, "fat" }
};

var item = list.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == "hat");
// Remove by value
list.Remove(item.Key);
// Remove by key
list.Remove(0);
```

Print the results

```
foreach (var kvp in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: It only works when I type in the word, but it doesn't remove the index like I stated before in the example. I want to be able to remove it either by entering the index number or entering the word along with the index number next to it.

Comment: you want to enter `0.hat` to remove the value?

Comment: No, either allow them to enter '0' to remove hat or enter 'hat' to remove it, but regardless which they enter I also want the index to go away. 

I figured out how to remove the element, but whenever I would enter '0', 'hat' would go away, but then 'mat's index became 0 when it should be 1... if that makes any sense

Comment: the "index" is a behind-the scenes thing with a list, and not really meant to be messed with. the list is dynamic, so if you remove an element, everything squishes together to take up the space where that element used to be. you need to look into dictionary type to do what you are talking about.

Comment: ... or even sortedlist, if that's really what you want. ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx for all the options as well as examples

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using list, use dictionary, where key would be an index of item. In this case, you'll preserve original indices of items, when you remove one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove by data

```
list.Remove(answer);
```

Remove by index

```
var index = list.FindIndex(i => i == answer);

    list.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: Should I then create a function for it?

Comment: If you want to call this function from different location for that work,yes you should.

Answer (score 0):

Original question:

> how to "remove an item along with its index number from a list by either
>   entering their index number or typing the word in."

There are a lot of ways to do this in C#. There are even multiple types. You've discovered one, `List<T>`, and that's certainly one way to do it, but probably not the best. You could also do an array of strings. There are several other types of collections available in the [`Systems.Collections.Generic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace, along with `List<T>`.

**But easiest by far is to just use [`Dict<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).**

How? Look at examples in the link I provided, or do something like this:

```
var a = new Dictionary<int, string>(){
    {0, "hat"},
    {1, "mat"},
    {2, "fat"}
};

a.Remove(0); // remove by key
a.Where(i => i.Value != "mat"); // remove by value
```

Comment: "remove by key" means by entering index number, "remove by value" means by typing the word in. at the end of the sample here, you will only be left with a dictionary with one element: "fat".